# How to get the size of an array of objects? - No instance of overloaded function "std::size"

Tags: c++, arrays, size, unreal-engine4, sizeof

I'm running into a problem with C++ that should have an easy solution, but nothing I've tried yet seems to work.

How do I go about getting the size/number of elements of an array if both `std::size()` and `std::sizeof()` are throwing errors?

For context, `FString` is Unreal Engine's version of `std::string`. Each one is a class instance. I've got a guessing game class with a static array of `FString`s to query from. It looks a bit like;

```
FString UBullCow::Words[] = {"hello", "goodbye", etc...};

class UBullCow 
{
    static FString Words[];
    // etc.
}
```

So, as I understand it, I'm dealing with an array of pointers somewhere in the heap. So, in other words, an array of integers, right?

Well, in one of the class' private functions, I need the size of the Words array. Here's what I've tried;

```
std::size(Words);
```

> Err(304): no instance of overloaded function "std::size" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (FString [])

```
std::sizeof(Words)/std::sizeof(Words[0]);
```

> Err(40): expected an identifier

Why wouldn't `std::size(Words)` work here? Is there a workaround, or a fix? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should post a [mcve] that shows the error, and not snippets of (fake) C++ code.

Comment: It either needs to be `static FSring Words[3];`, or be replaced with something like `std::vector`.

Comment: @OP -- [Start with this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55f8fbde411cbe01).  Now add code to it so that you see the error you're claiming.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's a good point, give me a min. I'll update the question.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat solved the issue, I needed to define the size of the array when declaring. I thought when initializing it would do the work for me, forgot this was cpp.

Answer (score 0):

```
static FSring Words[];
```

When your C++ compiler processes this declaration this is the ***only*** thing this declaration specifies: `Words` is an array of some unspecified size. By definition it's size is not known.

Defining this array, in one translation unit, does not change this. Its size may be defined, in that translation unit. But its size is still unknown in any other translation unit, subsequent to this declaration.

Comment: That solved it, thanks! So if I want to add or remove words to my declaration, I'll have to remember to update that number I guess.

Comment: @FrootLoopEdibles Not if you use a `std::vector`.

Comment: There are ways to avoid it `const size_t n_Words;` and, in the translation unit `size_t UBullCow::n_Words=std::size(Words);`. then use `n_Words`.

Comment: `std::array` would make more sense in this situation.